# How to navigate to the Edit route after New in a Spine stack

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, spine.js

I'm using Spine.Stack and I'm trying to find the best way to end up at the Edit page for a new record that gets created. The spine/rails example on the site shows @navigate going back to the index listing, but I need to end up on the edit page the the record I've just created. Currently I have

```
item = WorkRequest.fromForm(e.target)
if item.save()
  @navigate '/work_requests', item.id, 'edit' if item
```

Now this does end up on the edit page but because the model is an Ajax one it then saves to the server and gets the server side ID, but at the point I call `@navigate` the item.id is the client side ID (c-##). Therefore the URL I end up at is `/work_requests/c-##/edit` which has no sever side equivalent.

As far as I can see, I have two options

1. Wait for the Ajax to respond and then navigate to edit with the server generated ID
2. Call navigate, but then update the URL once the Ajax save responds (when the edit form gets re-rendered with the server side ID.

Option 2 seems best in the spirit of the non-blocking interface, but I need to be sure that if the user does anything in the meantime, that the ID's will all sort themselves out. Option 1 seems safer but does force the user to wait for the save to complete before being able to edit it.

As a side note; the reason for the immediate edit is to create one or more child items (like lines on an invoice) and these all use the nested resource path `/work_requests/:id/work_request_lines`

Any help greatly appreciated, cheers.